# No me genera objetos de una clase especifica

Tags: java

Cuando trato de usar este codigo no me genera objetos y al imprimir dice que esta vacia.

```
List<Question> questions = new ArrayList();
ChoicesQuestion q = new ChoicesQuestion();
ChoicesAnswer a = new ChoicesAnswer();
q.setText("La tierra es redonda?");
q.setChoices().add(new Choice("Verdadero", true));
q.setChoices().add(new Choice("Falso", false));
questions.add(q);
System.out.println(q.setChoices().isEmpty());
```

Si necesitan ver la libreria completa aqui: https://github.com/BrandonRuizMorales/Test

Comment: Por favor mira [ask]. El codigo relevante debe estar en la pregunta, y no en un link.

Comment: Nada de todo ese codigo que pusiste genera error. En que parte de tu codigo esta el error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema esta en la clase `ChoicesQuestion` específicamente en el método `setChoices` dado que cada vez que llamas a ese método te retorna un `ArrayList` vacío.

Para que tu código funcione debería hacer lo siguiente:

1. En la declaración de la propiedad (clase ChoicesQuestion) inicializar tu lista de opciones

   `private Collection<Choice> choices = new ArrayList();`
2. Luego utilizar el método `getChoices()` para obtener dicha referencia

   `public Collection<Choice> getChoices() {
       return choices;
   }`

Quedaría así:

```
List<Question> questions = new ArrayList();
ChoicesQuestion q = new ChoicesQuestion();
ChoicesAnswer a = new ChoicesAnswer();
q.setText("La tierra es redonda?");
q.getChoices().add(new Choice("Verdadero", true));
q.getChoices().add(new Choice("Falso", false));
questions.add(q);
System.out.println(q.getChoices().isEmpty());
```

Answer (score 0):

**Opción Sencilla**

Cambia esta linea en tu clase `ChoicesQuestions`:

```
public Collection<Choice> setChoices() {

        return choices;
    }
```

He inicializa la colección en el constructor

public ChoicesQuestions(){
   this.choices = new ArrayList<>();
}

**Opción Rebuscada**

Así como lo tienes creará algo de confusión en el código pero puede ser valido para acortar un poco lo que escribes. (Personalmente me gusta mucho hacer esto en los set pero le he encontrado inconvenientes de debugueo y lectura )

Cambiaria esta linea en tu clase `ChoicesQuestions`:

```
public Collection<Choice> setChoices() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

por esta otra:

```
public Collection<Choice> setChoices(Choice choice) {
        choices.add(choice);
        return this;
    }
```

No sin antes inicializar la colección.

```
private Collection<Choice> choices = new ArrayList<>();
```

Esto también puede hacerse en el constructor para mayor seguridad.

Después llamaría de esta manera para agregar de manera continua:

```
q.setChoices(new Choice("Verdadero", verdadero))
 .setChoices(new Choice("Falso", false));
```